# How do I make my function "return a value in all control paths"?

Tags: c, function, cs50

I'm fairly new to programming, I'm trying to put together a function:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string name;

bool check(string word)
{
    for(int i = 0; i >= 9; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    
}
```

But when I try to compile, I receive the error message `error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]`. What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the warning, add a `return` at the end of `check`:

```
bool
check(string word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i >= 9; i++) {
        if (strcmp(name, word) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

// NOTE/FIX: fixes the warning
    return false;
}
```

---

But, the `for` loop in your `check` function does nothing (it does the *same* thing on each iteration), so you don't need the loop.

Also, note that you *never* initialize `name` to anything, so it will segfault because `string` is actually `char *`. You need to set it to a valid pointer value.

Here's a refactored version with a diagnostic test:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string name = "hello";

bool
check(string word)
{
    bool match;

    match = (strcmp(name,word) == 0) ? true : false;

    return match;
}

string testlist[] = {
    "hello", "world", NULL
};

int
main(void)
{

    for (string *cur = testlist;  *cur != NULL;  ++cur) {
        bool ok = check(*cur);
        printf("%s: %s\n",*cur,ok ? "match" : "fail");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
hello: match
world: fail
```

---

> Can you help me with the code in your first paragraph- it looks like it will simply return false at the end?

Sure. You are correct. It *just* adds a `return` statement [*with* a value] at the end.

Oops. I just noticed that your `for` loop will *never* be executed even *once*. That's because `i` is initialized to 0. But, the loop condition is `i >= 9`, which will be *false* on the first iteration.

In fact, the compiler's optimizer would detect this and completely elide the loop.

*If* you had wanted to loop [for some reason] 10 times, the correct `for` loop would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
```

*With* this corrected loop, the added `return` would *never* actually be executed. This is because the loop is now *guaranteed* to execute at least *once*.

It will try to loop 10 times. But, the `if` will either be true or false and, in *either* case it does a `return` from *within* the loop, so things stop right then and there.

It would never "fall out" of the loop to execute the final/added `return`.

But, the compiler can't "know" that.

Or, more to the point, it should still flag the lack of the `return` at the bottom, even if it does realize that it won't be executed in practice.

What it saw was that after the `for` loop was executed, it got to the bottom of the function, for a function that *returns* a value, and there was *no* `return` statement [with value] for that code path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Craig- give me a few minutes to parse your answer!

Comment: Can you help me with the code in your first paragraph- it looks like it will simply return false at the end?

Comment: I think I (hopefully) have enough to be able to diagnose what has gone wrong and fix it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop never executes any iterations. In `for(int i = 0; i >= 9; i++)`, `i` is initialized to zero, and then the loop executes only while `i >= 9`. That is not true (zero is not greater than or equal to nine), so the loop does not execute. Program control proceeds to after the loop, where you have no more code, just the end of the function. So the function exits without using a `return` statement, so no value is returned. Hence the compiler warns you.

If you change the loop to `for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)`, then the loop will execute, and, with the code you have inside the loop, a `return` statement will definitely be executed. However, the Clang and GCC compilers still both warn. Presumably, they do this because there is a hypothetical code path in which the loop ends and the function exits as described above. That cannot happen, but both compilers fail to deduce it, which I find a bit surprising. Since they fail to recognize the path without the `return` cannot be executed, they issue a warning.

One way to avoid the warning is to put a `return` statement at the end of the function.

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for your answer. If I put a return statement e.g. ```return false``` at the end of the function, won't that simply mean that the function will return false in all cases, defeating the purpose of the loop?

Comment: @BlueKhakis: A statement located after the loop is executed after the loop. Or, if a statement in the loop returns, the statement after the loop is not executed at all.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will go back to my code and try again.